# SVG icons show broken image when inserted via a URL

Tags: html, css, svg

I've created a simple ***img*** tag and set its *src* to a url as shown below:

```
<img className={"componentImageContainer thumbnailIcon"}
   src="https://componentscendeveussa01.blob..../SVGLogo.svg" />
```

This method works fine for all filetypes (png, jpegs, jpgs, bmp) and I'm certain there is no issue in the rendering process as it shows the SVG perfectly if a local path is used. Also, there is no issue with the url because not only are they present in the database but also can be downloaded but putting the url in the browser address bar.
 I have tried *object* tag, setting source via backround-image property in css and checking the content-type that is set in the response headers. It is of type application/octet-stream (same as all other file types). What could then be the reason that a broken image is shown whenever an SVG is fetched.

Comment: application/octet-stream is no good. I'm surprised this works with any other image types.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to outline the svg and upload it. I had the same issue. The font in the svg was not working in the url. So I outlined the svg in Illustrator. Worked fine.

Comment: What do you mean by the font not 'working'? Was the image broken? Or not showing properly?

Comment: When I made a svg logo. I used a specific font. It was not embedded in the file and server. So the image looked broken. Then I outlined it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with fonts or outlining for me. As I mentioned in the question, SVG is not the issue, the process of uploading and rendering contains the problem.